# How do I attach ASP.net's default Application User to application specific model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

This is my application specific model

```
  public class Employer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }


    }
```

This is asp.net's default setup for creation of this model

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,EmployerName")] Employer employer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

           //was hoping solution would be as easy as..
           //employer.User = HttpContext.User;
           //but that is not working neither is anything else I find

            _context.Add(employer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(employer);
    }
```

When the Employer model is created no ApplicationUser is set to it. How do I go about getting the user from the current session and setting it to a model instance on creation. I am new to the asp.net framework so forgive me for my lack of understanding. Thank You so much for your reading over this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is ASP Identity and the user has logged in:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    employer.User = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == currentUserId);
    _context.Add(employer);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Another option would be to store the user in session.

Comment: I don't believe it is asp identity but thank you for bringing that to my attention. I have seen other suggestions calling to use the User.Identity.GetUserId(); method but Identity does not seem to have the method .GetUserId(); leading me to believe I'm not in ASP identity. Thank you for your help.

Comment: See if your project has a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`. If it does, GetUserId is an extension method so add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` to the top of the controller.